# Change User Profile Fields from modules - $form fields not available - Ubercart Roles

Tags: ubercart, users, forms

I have been attempting to change various fields on the user profile to make it more user friendly, most of it going well. However, when I try to access $form for the main user profile via `dpm($form)` in `MODULE_NAME_form_alter` not every field rendered onto the page is available. I have been trying to alter the profile forever with no luck!

```
function admin_dashboard_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    if($form_id == 'user_profile_form'){
        //change main user profile "Ubercart Roles" form field
        $form['uc_roles']['#title'] = t('Member Expiration');
        $form['uc_roles']['#collapsible'] = FALSE;
        $form['uc_roles']['#collapsed'] = FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! My module name was alphabetically before the other modules..."A" (admin_dasboard) comes before "U" (ubercart_roles). I was able to go into the drupal_system table and set my modules weight to 1, where before it was set to 0, the same as Ubercart. Hope this helps someone.